# Error 440 After I add application.displayalerts = false

Tags: excel, vba

When I add Application.DisplayAlerts = false and Application.DisplayAlerts = True either side of sheets("Sheet2").Delete I get the 440 error.

Not sure what the issue is but it runs no problem without the application.displayalerts.

I have been googling for ages I have tried a couple things mentioned on other questions posted on here. I feel like maybe i need another line of code or something.

Code that isnt working:

```vb
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

     Dim numberCopies As Long
            Dim currentRow As Long
            Dim j As Long
            Dim sht As Worksheet
            Set sht = Sheets("sheet3")
            currentRow = 2

     Do While Not IsEmpty(sht.Cells(currentRow, 1))
                numberCopies = sht.Cells(currentRow, 1)
                For j = 2 To numberCopies
                    sht.Rows(currentRow).Copy
                    sht.Rows(currentRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                    currentRow = currentRow + 1
                Next j
                currentRow = currentRow + 1
            Loop
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            sht.Columns(1).Delete
        Dim Path As String
        Dim Filename1 As String
        Dim Filename2 As String

     Path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    Filename1 = Range("B1")  
    Filename2 = Range("D1")




        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
        Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True



        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename1 & "-" & Filename2 & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV

       MsgBox "This usage file as been saved in the same folder as the Usage Upload Creator, it is saved as " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & " This workbook will now close and you can upload your usage file on CPQ. Thank You."
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        End Sub
```

I just dont want the "are you sure you want to delete the sheet" alert popping up.

Comment: Well first off the p in private Sub is on its own line. Other than that, what line is the error at? Does it work without the DisplayAlerts? Owh and make sure Sheet2 and Sheet1 do exist in the Workbook you're working in.

Comment: The p was me after i pasted the code. 
the code with issues: 

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
    Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True 

it works without the application.displayalerts

Comment: I tried those lines but it's not giving an error for me. Are you sure there is a sheet with the name "Sheet1" and "Sheet2".

Comment: What line does the error highlights if you hit debug?

Comment: I am sure about the sheet names as the code works but stops working when i add application.displayalert
it is deleting the page the macro button is on could that be the issue? 
I just removed sheets("sheet1").delete and there is no issue, but i need it to delete sheet 1 without the pop up

Comment: Ah, yes that is the problem. It gives an error when you delete the page that has the button.

Comment: is there a way to not have an error when i delete the page

Comment: Why is there an error when i have no alerts but no error when i have alerts, surely I can have no errors and no alerts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out in the comments what the problem was, The problem is that you cannot have the ActiveX button on the sheet that you're trying to delete. You can supress the error and alerts by using this:

```
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
    Sheets("Sheet1").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: you absolute hero. Thank you

Comment: Will do, but while I have you could i just ask if the sheets were protected what would be the code needed before the delete sheets to unprotect the sheets so that they could be deleted

where do i mark the answer as accepted - found it the big arrow

Comment: I am unsure, I think `.Unprotect` is a thing. but never used it myself.